# Formatted text in the command window

Tags: matlab

I know of the [cprintf](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/cprintf-display-formatted-color-text-in-command-window) Undocumented Matlab way of changing the color and other font properties in the command window but I also saw this [symbols in plots](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/greek-letters-and-special-characters-in-graph-text.html).  This shows that Matlab supports TeX markup in plots at least.  I played with it for a while and found it very useful.  So much so that I wanted to find a way to include this in the command window.

I first tried `sprintf('\color{red} Something\n')` and was rewarded with an error that `\c` is not a recognized escape sequence.  Google was no help either.

This is a way to use the some of the other formatting options in the command window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command window doesn't support TeX. Sorry. The TeX support is part of the routines that generate the figures, not the code that displays the command window.

In essence, the command window is, by modern standards, a pretty boring terminal emulator. There's not much you can do with it.

If you're looking for something to do math in that generates fancy notebooks on the fly that combine the commands you type and their results in a nice-to-read, modern way, you might just want to avoid Matlab and have a look at Jupyter (formerly IPython) Notebooks, which of course support MathJax (and thus, LaTeX math syntax): https://try.jupyter.org/